# Скачивание файла через REST: как прописать имя и расширение?

Tags: java, http, rest, header

У меня есть сервис, скачивающий XLSX-файл. Клиент стучится в контроллер и браузер скачивает файл.

Контроллер:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/file", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody byte[] getReport() throws IOException {
    return service.getReportAsExcel();
}
```

Проблема в том, что файл приходит без имени и расширения, просто file. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы файл приходил с именем и расширением? Возможно, надо что-то прописать в хэдерах?

Comment: [header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.xslt"')](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Content-Disposition)

Comment: [список вопросов на ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=content+disposition+attachment+%5Bjava%5D)